# Why is my fetch function sending empty strings?

Tags: javascript, php

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = nameInput.value;
    var email = emailInput.value;
    var amount = amountInput.value;
    console.log(name);
    let data = {
        name : name,
        email : email,
        amount : amount,
    }
    fetch('validator.php', {
        method : 'POST',
        body : JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.error(error);
    })
});
```

Manually inputting a name in the PHP file makes it work, so the problem is clearly how the information is being sent. It's not in the HTML because of the `console.log`, so any ideas?

```
<?php
    // User data to be displayed later
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $amount = $_POST["amount"];
    // Check for email format
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      echo "Please enter a valid email";
    }
    // JSON array
    $info = array($name,$email,$amount);
    json_encode($info);
?>
```

Up until the `console.log`, the information is correct, and it prints correctly. However, I'm getting this error on my browser:

> Notice:  Undefined index: name in **C:\laragon\www\validator.php** on line 4
> Notice:  Undefined index: email in **C:\laragon\www\validator.php** on line 5

> Notice:  Undefined index: amount in **C:\laragon\www\validator.php** on line 6
> Please enter a valid email

Here's the html of the form I am using:

```
<form action="validation.php" method="POST" class="text-center" id="form">
    <label for="name" class="form-label" style="color: #1D1C52; font-weight: bold;">Name</label>
    <div class="mb-4 w-50">
        <input
          type="name"
          id="name"
          name="name"
          class="form-control input-field"
          required
        />
 
      </div>
      <label for="email" class="form-label" style="color: #1D1C52; font-weight: bold;">Email</label>
      <div class="mb-4 w-50">
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          class="form-control input-field"
          required
        />

      </div>
      <label for="amount" class="form-label" style="color: #1D1C52; font-weight: bold;">Amount</label>
      <div class="mb-4 w-50">
        <input
          type="number"
          id="amount"
          name="amount"
          class="form-control input-field"
          required
        />
      </div>

    <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row gx-0">
    <div class="col-6 ps-5">
        <div class="clear-btn text-muted" id="clearButton">Clear fields</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 pe-5 ps-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" style="color: white; background-color: #1D1C52;" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </div>

    </div>                  
  </form>
```

Comment: Try echoing $_REQUEST - perhaps `$posts = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['body']));`

Comment: Please show html of that form

Comment: Did you check the network tab in the dev tools?

Comment: I added the html

Comment: What can I check in the dev tools?

Comment: If the body are actually sent

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php You have to use `json_decode` probably

Comment: that's the entire problem lol!

how would i know

Comment: Google it next time :)

Comment: Arnt these id's wrong, shoudn't they be `var name = name.value; var email = email.value; var amount = amount.value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typically instead of sending json to PHP, you'll want to make a form object.

```
const formData = new FormData();
const nameField = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]');
formData.append('name', nameField.value);
```

then use formData as your body, and don't set the fetch's content type at all.

but, since you are literally sending a form, there is an even easier way. you can make a formData from a form element.

```
const formData = new FormData(formElement);
```

then just use that as your body.

alternately if you must send your data as JSON, rather than a normal request, you will need to parse the request directly, rather than using `$_POST` variables in PHP.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```